# How can I import modules onto Webpack?

Tags: jquery, node.js, webpack

I have installed webpack to use with Flask. When my app.js file looks like this:

```js
import "../styles/index.scss";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle";
import "../components/sidebar";

window.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  window.console.log("dom ready 12");
  console.log("Ggg");
});
```

everything works normally. But when I add

```js
import "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js";
```

Then this file is not read anymore, eventhough the webpack watch process isn't throwing any errors. I know the file is not read because the console logs I run in it no longer appear in the browser console. Why is that?

Tried various variations of the import code:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = $;
```

```
import * as $ from 'jquery/dist/jquery.min';
window.$ = $;
```

```
import * from "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js";
```

Etc. But I can't seem to find the right one.

EDIT:

I have also tried using the Provide Plugin (as suggested in the first Answer below, see my comment there), however to no avail.
This is how my webpack.common.js file looks like:

```
const glob = require("glob");
const Path = require("path");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const WebpackAssetsManifest = require("webpack-assets-manifest");

const getEntryObject = () => {
  const entries = {};
  glob.sync(Path.join(__dirname, "../src/application/*.js")).forEach((path) => {
    const name = Path.basename(path, ".js");
    entries[name] = path;
  });
  return entries;
};
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: getEntryObject(),
  output: {
    path: Path.join(__dirname, "../build"),
    filename: "js/[name].js",
    publicPath: "/static/",
    assetModuleFilename: "[path][name][ext]",
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: "all",
    },

    runtimeChunk: "single",
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery"
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: Path.resolve(__dirname, "../vendors"), to: "vendors" },
      ],
    }),
    new WebpackAssetsManifest({
      entrypoints: true,
      output: "manifest.json",
      writeToDisk: true,
      publicPath: true,
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "~": Path.resolve(__dirname, "../src"),
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.mjs$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        type: "javascript/auto",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
        type: "asset",
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Relevant lines in my HTML code are:

```
{{ javascript_pack('app', 'app2', attrs='charset="UTF-8"') }}
<script>$('#my-select')</script>
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "app.css": "/static/css/app.css",
  "app.js": "/static/js/app.js",
  "app2.js": "/static/js/app2.js",
  "entrypoints": {
    "app": {
      "assets": {
        "js": [
          "/static/js/runtime.js",
          "/static/js/vendors-node_modules_bootstrap_dist_js_bootstrap_bundle_js-node_modules_jquery_dist_jquery_js.js",
          "/static/js/app.js"
        ],
        "css": [
          "/static/css/app.css"
        ]
      }
    },
    "app2": {
      "assets": {
        "js": [
          "/static/js/runtime.js",
          "/static/js/app2.js"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "js/vendors-node_modules_bootstrap_dist_js_bootstrap_bundle_js-node_modules_jquery_dist_jquery_js.js": "/static/js/vendors-node_modules_bootstrap_dist_js_bootstrap_bundle_js-node_modules_jquery_dist_jquery_js.js",
  "runtime.js": "/static/js/runtime.js",
  "vendors/.gitkeep": "/static/vendors/.gitkeep",
  "vendors/images/.gitkeep": "/static/vendors/images/.gitkeep",
  "vendors/images/sample.jpg": "/static/vendors/images/sample.jpg",
  "vendors/images/webpack.png": "/static/vendors/images/webpack.png"
}
```

Comment: Thank you @isherwood, the reason I am using jQuery is for a specific module I wanted to use called multiselect.js ( http://loudev.com/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, jQuery is one of those plugins that get messed up in webpack's bundling process.

The recommended (and easiest) way to get jQuery working is to use the [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/#usage-jquery).

Inside your webpack.config.js, add the following block to the plugins array -

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
});
```

If you don't have a plugins array, just add the array as follows -

```
... // other configurations
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
    });
],
```

Edit 1: Try using cacheGroups inside splitChunks as follows -

```
splitChunks: {
  cacheGroups: {
    vendor: {
      test: /node_modules/,
      name: "vendor",
      chunks: "all",
      enforce: true,
    },
  },
},
```

This will ensure that ONE vendor.js file is created - hopefully the manifest file and/or browser won't have a tough time importing that file.

Edit 2: Switch to url_for() to possibly fix it.

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/vendor.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/runtime.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/app2.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I have tried to do this on my webpack.common.js file (i don't have webpack.config.js). Unfortunately this does not help. Watch compiles everything well, but I still get "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" on my web page console.

Comment: Could you add the contents of webpack.common.js to the question?
Also, you are supposed to inject the vendor/bundle script into the DOM before the main app script (especially if the app script relies on a vendor package like jquery).
Maybe also add the snippet where these script files are added to your html?

Comment: Thanks BkiD, I added the webpack config file to the question now, unfortunately I am having trouble understanding what you mean by the other things you said, but I think the relevant lines in my index.HTML code are:


{{ javascript_pack('app', 'app2', attrs='charset="UTF-8"') }}
<script>$('#my-select')</script>

Comment: Is the error pointing to that script? The _<script>$('#my-select')</script>_. Technically, all jquery should wait for the document to be ready before begining execution. Try using _<script>$(function () { console.log($); });</script>_ to see if you get a jQuery instance in your console. If yes, simple use the 'ready' function to wrap your jquery i.e. _<script>$(function () { $('#my-select') });</script>_

Comment: Indeed, the console error is pointing to that line. I tried replacing it with the line you provided, but the error is the same.
I also tried "    window.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  $('#my-select');
});" to no avail.

Comment: In the browser console - try to type the following to see if you get any jquery instances (all 4 as different commands) - 

window.jQuery,  window.$,  jQuery,  $

Comment: results of these 4 commands:
https://imgur.com/a/kg7Y8nt

Comment: Right - so jQuery is for sure not being imported. Before we get to inspecting the bundle, try this - If you are still importing jquery in your app.js -- try 1. removing it 2. Importing jquery BEFORE the bootstrap bundle.

Comment: As a final resort, you could use [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) to analyze the bundle to check if jquery actually makes it to the final output.

Comment: import "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js";
I put this before the bootstrap import, this results in the console.log command no longer being printed in the console, indicating to me that the file is no longer being loaded effectively.

Comment: Any reasons for using the dist/jquery.min.js file? Try using - 
import $ from 'jquery';
/* and optionally assigning it to these 2 variables on the window object as well */
window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = $;

Comment: bundle analyzer results: https://imgur.com/a/TGVdJst

Comment: I did this now, using the 3 lines you provided instead of the one with min.js, but the result is the same.
also, if I add just the 1st line, I get an error from "watch" during compilation, complaining that I am not using the "$"

Comment: So, we might have some conflicting steps here. By default, you need to EITHER use import $ from 'jquery' at the beginning for your app.js OR use the ProvidePlugin. Could you try once again, by removing one of the two? Also try adding a console.log($) to your app.js

Comment: So I removed the relevant ProvidePlugin lines (    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery"
    }),    ), while keeping the relevant app.js lines (     import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = $;      ) - The result is the same. Adding the console.log($) command in the addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded" function makes no change. 

If I keep the ProvidePlugin lines and remove the app.js import lines, but add the console.log($) line after loading, I get a compile error saying $ is not defined.

Comment: When you say makes no change - do you mean the rest of your console.logs show up - but the jquery stuff doesn't? Shouldn't there be an undefined if it runs? Could you try using window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded") instead of window.document.....

Comment: I tried it now after removing ".document", but still no change, and by that I mean that the "regular" console.log command from this app.js file, which would be printed if it weren't for the import attempts, is not printing, i.e. the entire app.js file is being ignored, but the console.log command from app2.js is still being printed.

Comment: Interesting - can you check your 'build' folder to confirm that webpack is only outputting app.js and app2.js? Are there no other js files? Are you forgetting to somehow load the 'vendor' files in the html?

Comment: The build/js folder contains 4 file:   app.js,   app2.js,    runtime.js,     vendors-node_modules_bootstrap_dist_js_bootstrap_bundle_js-node_modules_jquery_dist_jquery_js.js     1/2

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by loading the "vendor" files in the HTML, the only line I had that could be relevant is "{{ javascript_pack('app', 'app2', attrs='charset="UTF-8"') }}
"

Comment: Right - so there's your answer! I thought it was weird when I was the name of the bundle in the analyzer results (shouldn't have disregarded it). When your page loads, can you check the Network Tab (Tick Disable Cache - and do a Hard Reload - Ctrl+Shift+R/Cmd+Shift+R) - does the website ever load the _vendors-node_modules_bootstrap_dist_js_bootstrap_bundle_js-node_modules_jquery_dist_jquery_js.js_ file? Because that's where your jquery module is.

Comment: It does try to load it but it gets a 404:
GET http://localhost:5000/static/js/vendors-node_modules_bootstrap_dist_js_bootstrap_bundle_js.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)
even though the file is there...

Comment: correction: the file it's trying to load has a different name than the actual file name. it is trying to load vendors-node_modules_bootstrap_dist_js_bootstrap_bundle_js.js but the actual file name is vendors-node_modules_bootstrap_dist_js_bootstrap_bundle_js-node_modules_jquery_dist_jquery_js.js

I will try to look for where this instruction is given.

Comment: Aha! Can you also look at the manifest.json file to ensure that this file path exists and is mapped to the correct file?

Comment: I added manifest.json to the original question now. Looking at it, it seems that this very long path is defined correctly, to the longer version that contains the word "jquery", but it's not the one that the browser is trying to load.

Comment: Right - so let's try to make this easier to read to begin with - you could use the 'cacheGroups' concept in your webpack.common.js - I'm updating my answer with the codeblock.

Comment: I see that the erroneous, shorter document name is represented in the <script> line in the HTML file, which is seemingly auto-generated by the "{{ javascript_pack('app', 'app2', attrs='charset="UTF-8"') }}" line. Trying to understand what happens there.

Comment: is splitChunks parallel to module, resolve, plugins keys? I see there is a splitChunks inside optimization

Comment: No - it's inside optimization (which is parallel to plugin, etc.). You already are using splitChunks in your webpack.common.js - you need to simply replace the config object inside it with my version.

Comment: current webpack.common.js 
https://pastebin.com/dymnQ8ji after replacing existing splitChunks with new splitChunks

Comment: It seems that the browser is still being instructed to load the erroneous URL

Comment: Woah - does the erroneous URL exist anywhere in the manifest.json?

Comment: nope - current manifest.json looks good from here 
https://pastebin.com/eZ832eBi

Comment: to see the problematic, auto-generated html <script> line:
https://imgur.com/OBIngyJ

Comment: Okay - so the error is less to do with webpack and more to do with javascript_pack used inside flask. Could you try using url_for() instead for all the file you need? Look at Edit 2 for a properly formatted version

Comment: current app.py
https://pastebin.com/bkkVXs6Z

Comment: We have broken through this now. JQuery loads properly. I am in awe of your patience and persistence. Cannot possibly thank you enough.

Comment: Wohhooo! Finally! That was a real long ride! \m/ Thanks for sticking by and being patient with all my request as well! :)